# Recover backup copy of a ubuntu linux installation on a usb stick using dd

Tags: ubuntu, boot, usb

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Recover backup copy of a ubuntu linux installation on a usb stick using dd](https://superuser.com/questions/141730/recover-backup-copy-of-a-ubuntu-linux-installation-on-a-usb-stick-using-dd)

I installed Ubuntu 10.04 on a usb stick in persistent install mode. So I could boot the laptop or my desktop computer with the stick, at boot time. Once I needed the 8GB stick for another purposes so I thought about coyping it to my desktop doing from mac os x:

```
dd if=/dev/disks3s of=/Users/jack/Desktop/usb_copy
```

Now I am trying to do the opposite, after having used the stick, which was formatted to NTFS, just doing

```
dd if=/Users/jack/Desktop/usb_copy of=/dev/disks3s
```

but although I can see that almost of the files are there, I can not boot again. IT is also strange the the file permissions are kind of strange, something like _user

What can I do?

Comment: I have no idea why you can't boot, but I have a guess about the part with the file permissions. Your Mac OS uses different UIDs than your Linux, so it shows something totally off.

Comment: This is an exact-duplicate from the same person and about the same time as the question referred by `Nifle`. Should be closed.